# No value given for one or more required parameters vb.net oledb

Tags: vb.net, oledb

```
Public Class ViewPhoneRecords
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim dbProvider As String
Dim dbSource As String
Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim sqlquery As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim con1 As New OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Database.accdb")

Private Sub SaveBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn.Click


    Dim sqlupdate As String
    ' Here we use the UPDATE Statement to update the information. To be sure we are 
    ' updating the right record we also use the WHERE clause to be sureno information
    ' is added or changed in the other records
    sqlupdate = "UPDATE PhoneRecords SET Forename=@Forename, Surname=@Surname, Address=@Address, PhoneModel=@PhoneModel, PhoneNumber=@PhoneNumber, Postcode=@Postcode WHERE IDNum='" & IDTextBox.Text & "'"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlupdate, con1)
    ' This assigns the values for our columns in the DataBase. 
    ' To ensure the correct values are written to the correct column

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Forename", ForenameTextBox1.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Surname", SurnameTextBox1.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Address", AddressTextBox1.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@PhoneModel", PhoneModelTextBox1.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@PhoneNumber", PhoneNumberTextBox1.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Postcode", PostcodeTextBox1.Text))

    con1.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MsgBox("Row(s) Inserted !! ") 'Displays message box informing the user that the database has been added to

    con1.Close() 'Connection closed
    Me.Refresh()
End Sub
```

This is supposed to update a selected record in a datagrid view. However, when I click the 'Save changes' button, an error is given; "No value given for one or more parameters." Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` instead of `cmd.Parameters.Add`